# Sum values get multiplied by the number of records

Tags: sql, oracle

I am querying the total amount of payments and account statements of the last month in my table. I use following query to do this

```
SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE, COALESCE(SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY),0) AS PAYMENTS,SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) as STATEMENTS
    FROM DIM_ACCOUNT DA
        JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
        LEFT JOIN FACT_AS_TRANSACTION FAT ON DA.ID = FAT.ACCOUNT_ID
        JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FAT.VALUE_DATE_ID = DD.ID
        LEFT JOIN FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP ON DA.ID = FPP.ORDERING_ACCOUNT_ID
        JOIN DIM_PAY_PAYMENT_METHOD DPPM ON FPP.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID = DPPM.ID
    WHERE DD.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND FPP.CREATION_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND DPPM.DIRECT_DEBIT_FLAG = 'N' 
        AND FAT.DEBIT_CREDIT_MARK = 'Debit'
    GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE
    HAVING SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) != 0;
```

I loaded up 3 payments:

> Payment A with amount 2500
>
> Payment B with amount 2500
>
> Payment C with amount 2000
>
> Payment D with amount 500

I hope to expect a total amount of 7500. But when I execute this query I get 30000. This is the same as 7500 * 4 (4 records in my payments table). I think I might join something wrong. The question is what?

Comment: If you really want LEFT JOIN's instead of regular inner joins, move those tables' conditions from WHERE clause to the ON clauses.

Comment: You have a Cartesian product happening for each id/code combination.  The best method to resolve this is to aggregate before doing the `join`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where is breaking the left so it is just join
Or if you bring the condition up in to the join you can do a left
Two sums like that rarely work as they give each other duplicate rows
Take out the group by and just select the values and you will see any   duplicates
4 rows in FAT will give you 4 rown in FPP
Try as two separate and see if you get the correct answer

```
SELECT DA.ID, DDO.CODE
     , COALESCE(SUM(FPP.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY),0) AS PAYMENTS
     , SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY)             as STATEMENTS
  FROM DIM_ACCOUNT DA
  JOIN DIM_DATA_OWNER DDO 
        ON DA.DATA_OWNER_ID = DDO.ID
  JOIN FACT_AS_TRANSACTION FAT 
        ON DA.ID = FAT.ACCOUNT_ID
       AND FAT.DEBIT_CREDIT_MARK = 'Debit'
  JOIN DIM_DATE DD 
        ON FAT.VALUE_DATE_ID = DD.ID
       AND DD.CAL_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  JOIN FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP 
        ON DA.ID = FPP.ORDERING_ACCOUNT_ID 
       AND FPP.CREATION_DATE >= TO_DATE('2015-09-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')     
  JOIN DIM_PAY_PAYMENT_METHOD DPPM 
        ON FPP.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID = DPPM.ID       
       AND DPPM.DIRECT_DEBIT_FLAG = 'N'              
 GROUP BY DA.ID, DDO.CODE
HAVING SUM(FAT.AMOUNT_IN_DEFAULT_CURRENCY) != 0;
```